# function overloading by return type

Tags: perl

Perl is one of such language which supports the function overloading by return type.

Simple example of this is [wantarray()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/wantarray.html).

Few nice modules are available in CPAN which extends this wantarray() and provide overloading for many other return types. These modules are [Contextual::Return](http://search.cpan.org/~dconway/Contextual-Return-0.004003/lib/Contextual/Return.pm) and [Want](http://search.cpan.org/~robin/Want-0.21/Want.pm). Unfortunately, I can not use these modules as both of these fails the perl critic with perl version 5.8.9 (I can not upgrade this perl version).

So, I am thinking to write my own module like Contextual::Return and Want but with very minimal. I tried to understand Contextual::Return and Want modules code, but I am not an expert.

I need function overloading for return types  BOOL, OBJREF, LIST, SCALAR only.

Please help me by providing some guidelines, how can I start for it.

Comment: I don't know, CPAN says your version of perl should work just fine for Contextual::Return … Anyway, providing an extra argument (context=>'BOOL') might be simpler than hacking up an extra module

Comment: If your Perl::Critic doesn't like it, why don't you add a rule so it knows how to tread these cases correctly?

Comment: These rules are enforced by our client. It's policy that the cpan modules should also pass perl critic with severity 5 if used by

Comment: I'd recommend sending Damian Conway an email and asking him what he thinks you ought to do. I'd suggest forking Contextual::Return, fixing the Perl::Critic violations, and submitting the changes back to Damian, if he's interested in them.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the text in the question. I thought your code didn't pass when you used them, but you said that those modules do not pass the test. OK. Forget that comment, then.

Comment: @zostay: writing functionality like these modules provide is all but impossible to do properly without infringing some prescription of *Perl Best Practices*. In particular subroutines cannot accept code blocks as parameters without using prototypes, so the rules are immediately broken. The recommendations were never intended to be applied so rigorously.

Comment: As evidence that "the recommendations were never intended to be applied so rigorously", note that Contextual::Return and _Perl Best Practices_ are both by Damian Conway. He has obviously considered PBP's recommendations and decided that it is appropriate for Contextual::Return to deviate from some of them. (Which, incidentally, is exactly the way that PBP itself says its guidelines should be used.)

Answer (score 6):

Modules that play with Perl's syntax in the way that `Contextual::Return` and `Want` do are pretty much bound to fall foul of `Perl::Critic`. In this case the main transgressions are occasionally disabling `strict` and using subroutine prototypes, which are minimal.

I personally believe it is a foolish rule that insists that all code must pass an arbitrary set of tests with no exceptions, but I also think that any code that behaves very differently depending on the context in which it is called is likely to be badly designed and difficult to understand and maintain. It is rare to see even `wantarray` used, as Perl generally does the *right thing* without you having to explain.

I think you may have come across a module that looks interesting to use, and want to incorporate it into your code somehow. Can you change my mind by showing an example of a subroutine that would require the comprehensive context checking that you describe?

Comment: +1 on the foolishness, and doubly so on code that you didn't even write. `Perl::Critic` is not the be-all and end-all of code quality; being a widely used Perl module should be more than sufficient.

Comment: @duskwuff: But the problem, as always, is likely to be persuading management of this, as they feel secure in knowing that they have enforced a standard of any sort and can say so in their defence if necessary.

Comment: A solid counterargument could perhaps be that lots of essential Perl core modules fail perlcritic as well. (For example, `CGI.pm` has eight failures, and `Moose.pm` has one. But nobody sane would argue that you should roll your own CGI module, or avoid Moose.)

Comment: Even `strict.pm` and `warnings.pm` fail the test!